# Triangle inequality in $\kappa $ metric space where $\kappa = 2^n $

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$X$ is a $\kappa $ - metric space if $$d: X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$$ satisfies the following  :
  $$a)\ \ d(x,y)\ge 0;\\b)\ \ d(x,y)=d(y,x);\\c)\ \ d(x,y)=0\ \ \iff\ x=y;\\d)\ \ d(x,z)\le \kappa\left[d(x,y)+d(y,z) \right];\kappa\neq1.$$

I have to prove this for the map $$d:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$$ such that $$d(x,y)=(x-y)^{2^n}$$

The first $3$ properties are proved easily . For the property $d)$ it is given that $\kappa=2^n $ will be it ,i.e. ,

$$d(x,z)\le 2^n\left[d(x,y)+d(y,z) \right]$$

So I tried induction. For $n=1$ it is $$d(x,z)\\=(x-z)^2\\=((x-y)+(y-z))^2\\ \le 2\left[ (x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2\right]\\=2\left[d(x,y)+d(y,z) \right]$$

So now assume it holds upto $n$. We take $$d(x,y)=(x-y)^{2^{n+1}}$$ And we have to prove that $$d(x,z)\le 2^{n+1}\left[ d(x,y)+d(y,z)\right].\\i.e.\ \ (x-z)^{2^{n+1}}\le 2^{n+1}\left[(x-y)^{2^{n+1}}+(y-z)^{2^{n+1}} \right]$$

Now this is how I proceeded :

$$d(x,z)\\=(x-z)^{2^{n+1}}\\=(x-z)^{{2^n}\cdot 2}\\=(x-z)^{2\cdot p};\ \ where\ \ p=2^n\\=(x-z)^p\cdot (x-z)^p\\ \le p\left[(x-y)^p+(y-z)^p\right]\cdot p\left[(x-y)^p+(y-z)^p\right] \left[  \ by\ \ induction\ \ hypothesis\ \right]\\=p^2\cdot \left[(x-y)^{p}+(y-z)^p\right]^2\\ \le(2^n)^2\cdot 2\left[ (x-y)^{2p}+(y-z)^{2p}\right]\\=2^{2n+1}\cdot \left[ (x-y)^{2^{n+1}}+(y-z)^{2^{n+1}}\right]$$

And arrived at a totally different inequation  than what was required.

Did I make any mistakes in the steps or the conclusion given is wrong $?$

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve not done anything wrong. Essentially you’re trying to prove by induction on $n$ that

$$(a+b)^{2^n}\le 2^n\left(a^{2^n}+b^{2^n}\right)\;.$$

But set $a=b=1$, and this becomes

$$2^{2^n}\le 2^n\left(1^{2^n}+1^{2^n}\right)=2^{n+1}\;,$$

which is clearly false for $n>1$. Thus, what you’re trying to prove simply isn’t true.

Comment: Thank you . Is it at all possible to find such constants $\kappa $ for inequations of this type $?$  I also tried  $d(x,y)=(x-y)^{2n}$ and tried to find the $\kappa$ for it but in vain .

Comment: @user118494: You’re welcome. I’ve not really thought about it, but my initial reaction would be to try to prove that it’s not possible. (My initial reactions have been known to be wrong, of course!)

Comment: So do you mean finding a suitable $\kappa $ in these two cases is possible $?$

Comment: @user118494: I don’t know; my inclination is to think that it’s not possible, but I’ve not actually given it enough thought for that to mean much.

Comment: @user118494: You’re welcome. I’m sorry that I can’t be more helpful off the top of my head.